# Can I change the type of stream I'm using without closing and reopening the socket in Java?

Tags: java, sockets

I'm doing some socket programming in Java and I'd like to be able to change between using the `ObjectOutputStream`, the `DataOutputStream`, and the `PrintWriter` all within the same socket/connection.  Is this possible and what is the best way to do it?

I've tried just creating both types of objects, for example `ObjectOutputStream` and `DataOutputStream`, but that doesn't seem to work.

The reason I want to switch between them is to, for example, send a text command `"INFO"` that signals I'm about to send an object with information or a command `"DATA"` signalling that I'm about to send data.  Any advice on the best way to do this is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only use one underlying stream type however you can get that data from anywhere.

```
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(s.getOutputStream()));


public static void writeObject(DataOutputStream dos, Serializable obj) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
    oos.writeObject(obj);
    oos.close();
    dos.writeUTF("OBJECT");
    byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
    dos.writeInt(bytes.length);
    dos.write(bytes);
    dos.flush();
}

public static void writeBytes(DataOutputStream dos, byte[] bytes) {
    dos.writeUTF("BYTES");
    dos.writeInt(bytes.length);
    dos.write(bytes);
    dos.flush();
}

public static void writeText(DataOutputStream dos, String text) {
    dos.writeUTF("TEXT");
    dos.writeUTF(text);
    dos.flush();
}
```

Comment: So to receive this, I'd use DataInputStream.ReadUTF() to get my command and then, in the case of an object, read the integer that specifies the number of bytes, and then finally open an ObjectInputStream on the bytes that I read from the DataInputStream.Read() method using the length that I obtained?

Comment: That works great.  Thank you for your help.  I added the read methods that I built to your answer, hopefully those are helpful to someone.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want the `*Stream` to convert to the `*Writer`.

You can do what you want to do with `*Stream`.

```
Socket s = new Socket();
DataOutputStream stream = new DataOutputStream( s.getOutputStream() );

byte[] bytes = "INFO".getBytes();
stream.write(bytes);
//....
bytes = "DATA".getBytes();
stream.write(bytes);
```